# Twiki/Source Control with fine-grained permissions for internal and external use

Tags: trac, twiki

We've been using trac and svn internally with fairly good results. Now we'd like to open up parts of our system to external vendors - eg. we'd like to create an area on the twiki for our external designer to upload images, document things, and so forth. We need to be able to restrict his access to only that part of the twiki.

Similarly we have external developers working on specific modules that we'd like to provide twiki and svn access to, but only for their subset of the project.

We started to do this with trac, then switched to pursuing basecamp, then basecamp alternatives, and then generally floundered.

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

We implemented this approach:

For Trac you could try [Fine Grained Permissions](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracFineGrainedPermissions) to control access to the wiki pages. Rest of privileges can be managed somehow with standard permissions.

For the SVN access, you can use the authorization method provided by your server.

We also have LDAP as authentication mechanism for both Trac and SVN.